# Internal error:TypeError: req.getConnection is not a function

Tags: mysql, node.js, express-session

Basically i am trying to connect to db using the below code and getting the error. Could someone help please?

Donno what needs to be done.
     below is the code for app.js that i am using
    app.js

```
var session = require('express-session');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var connection = require('express-session');


var index = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session({
secret:"ipsitatesting", 
resave:false, 
saveUninitialized:true,
rolling: true,
cookie: {
        expires: 9 * 100000
        }
   }));
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

   // Create Sql Connection
   app.use(connection(mysql, {
   host: "localhost",
   user: "root",
   password: "ipsita123",
   database: "project2",
   },'request'));


     app.use('/', index);
     app.use('/users', users);
     app.use('/login', function(req,res){
         res.render('Calculator Login');
     });
     app.use('/logout', index);
```

Below is the code for index.js

```
    index.js
    //route for viewing products
    router.post('/viewProducts', viewProducts);
    function viewProducts(req, res, next){
    //check if user has logged in
    try {

    var asin = req.body.asin;
    req.getConnection(function(err, conn) {.... etc etc }
```

Comment: What error specifically are you getting?

Comment: Internal error:TypeError: req.getConnection is not a function
POST /viewProducts 500 48.623 ms - 1199

Comment: this is resolved now. thanks